Friend optimized some python code of mine, what is it really doing?
A friend optimized some code I wrote. I was trying to make sense of it.
Using some actual values it boils down to this:
from itertools import cycle

list = sorted([8, 4, 6, 2])
c = cycle(list)

u = [set(next(c) for _ in range(2)) for _ in range(6)]
print(u)

This code prints
[{2, 4}, {8, 6}, {2, 4}, {8, 6}, {2, 4}, {8, 6}]
What I do not understand, is why the second pair is always {8, 6}, when the list is sorted?
Looking at set(next(c) for _ in range(2)), I thought it should always get the next from the cycle, so I was expecting [{2, 4}, {6, 8}, {2, 4}, {6, 8}, {2, 4}, {6, 8}]

Oh I see, the set() is unordered - it is intriguing to see though that it always un-orders things in the same way...?

Oh yeah, most hashes in Python are randomized, but small enough integers hash to themselves.

Actually Dict are also unordered originally! Nowdays it remembers insertion order with extra container type but internally it's using hash table like set would do, and worked like set.
Quote: Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

It's impossible to assess whether this is optimized without actual data. There are many inputs which exist that result in this code being suboptimal.

Maybe optimized isn't the best wording; he simplified it. My code was a factor of 6 lines longer...
